# Linear regression of same outcome, similar number of covariates and one unique covariate in each model

Tags: r, formula, linear-regression

I want to run linear regression for the same outcome and a number of covariates minus one covariate in each model. I have looked at the example on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251507/how-to-succinctly-write-a-formula-with-many-variables-from-a-data-frame?lq=1) but could that did not provide what I wanted.

Sample data

```
a <- data.frame(y = c(30,12,18), x1 = c(7,6,9),  x2 = c(6,8,5),
                x3 = c(4,-2,-3), x4 = c(8,3,-3), x5 = c(4,-4,-2))
m1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x4 + x5, data = a)    
m2 <- lm(y ~ x2 + x4 + x5, data = a)   
m3 <- lm(y ~ x3 + x4 + x5, data = a)
```

How could I run these models in a short way and and without repeating the same covariates again and again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300595/automatically-create-formulas-for-all-possible-linear-models) you could do this:

```
lapply(1:3, function(i){
    lm(as.formula(sprintf("y ~ x%i + x4 + x5", i)), a)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Backlin for your answer. I think I have not expressed my question clearly. In the models x4 and x5 are present in all models, but x1, x2 and x3 are exchangeable and are present only in one model separately.

Comment: Aha, no problem I'll update the answer. I was fooled by the extra `+` between `x1` and `x4` so I thought you wanted all in between too.