# Only return correlations with p< .05 or r > .4 in r

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe 15257 * 2050 and I am trying to isolate the correlated items with a correlation higher than r = .4 and lower than p < .05. I have the correlations working, however I cannot visualise the data effectively:

```
Final_Dataset <- Final_Dataset[, colSums(is.na(Final_Dataset)) != nrow(Final_Dataset)]
Final_Dataset <- Final_Dataset[,-grep("Date|factor|character|logical", sapply(Final_Dataset, class))]
table(sapply(Final_Dataset, class))
Final_Dataset <- as.data.frame(scale(Final_Dataset))

longformData <- as.data.frame(cor(Final_Dataset[sapply(Final_Dataset, is.numeric)]), method = "pearson")
longformData <- corr.test(Final_Dataset, adjust = "none", ci = F)
```

Any ideas, I have tried corrplot and other alternatives, but nothing seems to work for me. Ideally, I would limit the graph to significant correlations.

Comment: Can you provide the initial value for `Final_Dataset`? That would make your example fully reproducible.

Comment: How can I best do that Andrew?

Comment: Before you run the first line of code that you provided, type `dput(Final_Dataset)` and post the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dataframe is massive and the dput function will take a long time

Comment: just use the `mtcars` dataset

Comment: You can try `dput(Final_Dataset[1:10,])`

Comment: Still too many vars

Comment: This question might be the most useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300595/automatically-create-formulas-for-all-possible-linear-models