Is there a way to shorten my loops with vector or matrix related functions?
Im writing a code to construct ARDL models in RStudio and I need to create every possbile model to then compare them, filter between them and so on. I have a data set with 13 regressors and the models can have different quantity of them inside (e.g. y = x1 + x2 + ... + x(n)) with the maximum of 13 regressors.
My data set contains 15 columns with data, dependent variable and 13 regressors.
The problem is the ARDL function in package "ARDL". I'm using auto_ardl function from this package. For my code it looks like this:
p_sign = ' + '
y = data_set
auto_fit(y, text_to_code(paste0("Y ~ ", d[i], p_sign,d[j]))))

where y is the data set, and text_to_code(paste0("Potr_momsa ~ ", d[i], p_sign,d[j]) is the formula for the model, where d[i] is the name of regressor from the vector d[1:13] of all names and text_to_code is the function that turns str to executable code.
You can find full details about formula in ARDL package documents. What is crucial is that formula should be written, for example, like this: y ~ x1 + x2, and it

should contain only variables that exist in the data provided through data plus some additional functions supported by dynlm (i.e., trend()).

The problem is the always changing number of possible regressors. The formula above has only 2 regressors (d[i] and d[j]) and the block of code for all possible 2 regressors models looks like this:
reg = c()
for (i in 1:length(d)) {
  for (j in 1:length(d)) {
    # Elements cannot be repeated, so code below prevents that
    cond_vec = c(d[i], d[j])
    condition = !cond_vec %in% cond_vec[duplicated(cond_vec)]
    s_reg = sum(i,j)
    
    if (any(condition == FALSE) == TRUE | any(reg == s_reg)) {
      next}

    reg = append(reg, s_reg)
    # The code for the model
    assign(paste0("p2_",i,"_",j,"_fit"), 
           auto_fit(y, text_to_code(paste0("Potr_momsa ~ ", d[i], p_sign,d[j]))))
      
  }
}

and code for model with, for example, 7 regressors, sadly, looks like this:
reg = c()
for (i in 1:length(d)) {
  for (j in 1:length(d)) {
    for (t in 1:length(d)) {
      for (i2 in 1:length(d)) {
        for (j2 in 1:length(d)) {
          for (t2 in 1:length(d)){
            for (i3 in 1:length(d)){
              # Elements cannot be repeated, so code below prevents that
              cond_vec = c(d[i], d[j], d[t], d[i2], d[j2], d[t2], d[i3])
              condition = !cond_vec %in% cond_vec[duplicated(cond_vec)]
              s_reg = sum(i,j,t,i2,j2,t2,i3)
              
              if (any(condition == FALSE) == TRUE | any(reg == s_reg)) {
                next}
              reg = append(reg, s_reg)

              # The code for the model
              assign(paste0("p7_",i,"_",j, '_', t, '_', i2, '_', j2, '_',
                            t2, '_', i3,"_fit"),
                     auto_fit(y, text_to_code(paste0("Potr_momsa ~ ", d[i], p_sign, d[j],
                                                     p_sign, d[t], p_sign, d[i2], p_sign,
                                                     d[j2], p_sign, d[t2], p_sign, d[i3]))))
                               
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}  

And I have 13 of this monsters in my code.
I know that R is slow with loops and better to use with vectors, but I'm still new to R and couldn't find a good solution for this loops. Ideally, I would like to have a one block of code to create all models or at least 13 small blocks (one for each number of possible regressors in the formula) of code without loops.
I really need to shorten this somehow because it takes too much time to run this code. I am almost sure there is some vector or matrix related commands in R that will help me, but I couldn't find them.
Here is the link for my data set if it helps: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aV3p8v9hFAeFLTHqHxU1y8YH_gs7bLu5?usp=sharing
I would really appreciate your help with this.
I've searched the internet for solution but couldn't find a suitable one for my problem.
The idea I had before is to create a 13 to 13 matrix of possible regressors and then loop through it's elements but couldn't find a way to loop through them in a mixed order without loops. By this moment I have some ideas that will probably allow me to use 13 blocks of code with only 2 loops inside, but I believe R have some functionality to shorten this task much more.

Take a look at utils::combn.

I might have an answer / example for a pair (n=2) of regressors (13*12 possibilities). With some copy-paste or other methods, it can be upgrade from n=2 to n=3, n=4 ....
However,  its unclear if auto_fit is mandatory (what is it?), or others methods to loop over auto_ardl   can be good. Also, what are you trying to compare? AIC?
My solution include the use of utils::combn (thanks @Limney )   to create a df/list , and looping with purrr::map() and as.formula().

But after a quick Google search , this question (and answers)  seems to be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5300595/13203906

It seems I'm somehow bad at Google search )) You've helped really much. Thank you!

Sometimes it takes courage to take a step back and rethink the problem in others ways
